# Access violation exception after deleting the head node of a doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, access-violation, head

This is my delete function

```
void deleteNode(Node** head, Node* deletingNode) {
    if (head == NULL || deletingNode == NULL)
        return;
    if (*head == deletingNode) {
        *head = deletingNode->next;
        displayNode(*head); //This is to check if the head has changed. And it has.
    }
    if (deletingNode->next != NULL)
        deletingNode->next->prev = deletingNode->prev;
    if (deletingNode->prev != NULL)
        deletingNode->prev->next = deletingNode->next;
    delete(deletingNode);
    return;
}
```

After I delete the head node and try do anything with the linked list, for example, display the whole linked list like so

```
void displayNode(Node* node) {
    cout << left << setw(4) << node->employee.empID
        << left << setw(20) << node->employee.empName
        << left << setw(8) << node->employee.empSalary
        << left << setw(25) << node->employee.empAddress
        << left << setw(15) << node->employee.empPhone
        << left << setw(2) << node->employee.depNo
        << left << setw(28) << node->employee.depName
        << left << setw(4) << node->employee.performance
        << '\n';
}
void displayAllNodes(Node* node) {
    displayColumnNames();
    while (node != NULL) {
        displayNode(node);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

An exception is thrown at the second line of the above block

```
Exception thrown at 0x78DBE26E (ucrtbased.dll) in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDDD. occurred
```

This ONLY happens when I delete the head node. Works just fine if I delete any other node.

So far I have tried making the double pointer in the deleteNode function into a single pointer but that didn't make a difference.

The whole code: https://codeshare.io/5oV8Jr

Comment: Show a [mcve]. I don't see anything obviously wrong with `deleteNode`. The problem likely lies elsewhere, in the way you set up the list in the first place, and/or the way you call `deleteNode`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm not sure how I could do a mre without messing things up. However the program is quite small around 500 lines https://codeshare.io/5oV8Jr

Comment: `0xDDDDDDDD` means you are dereferencing a deleted pointer that exists on the heap. Here is the explanation: `0xDDDDDDDD` is a magic code meaning Used by Microsoft's C++ debugging heap to mark freed heap memory see here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/487892)

Comment: ***I'm not sure how I could do a mre without messing things up.*** You need to use your debugger to figure this one out. Thankfully you have one of the best debuggers.

Comment: @drescherjm So it means the program is trying to access the head pointer I just deleted right? But I don't know how that would happen if head was changed to the node after head.

Comment: `deleteRecord(Node* node)` should be `deleteRecord(Node** node) {` the bug is caused by &node in deleteRecord(). This is related to what @IgorTandetnik mentioned.

Comment: `deleteRecord` takes `head` by value. Changes made to `head` inside the function are not visible to the caller: `head` in `mainMenu` is not updated, and becomes a dangling pointer. As I predicted, the problem lies in the code not shown; hence the need for a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed the problem. I'm new to C++ and am still having trouble with pointers. Still not sure what the double pointer does but the problem has been fixed for now.

Comment: I believe the answer shows an additional bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Following the fix from comments section(thanks to [drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) and [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik)), here's another bug I found and a quick fix to that.

I believe there's an issue is in this part of code:

```cpp
if (*head == deletingNode) {
  *head = deletingNode->next;
  displayNode(*head); //This is to check if the head has changed. And it has.
}
```

What if you have just 1 node in the linked list and you call `deleteNode()`. Now `head` and `deletingNode` points to the same node and `*head = deletingNode->next;` sets the head to `NULL` after which you're calling `displayNode(*head);` which will throw an error.

Quick fix:

```cpp
if (*head == deletingNode) {
  *head = deletingNode->next;
  if(*head != NULL)
    displayNode(*head); //This is to check if the head has changed. And it has.
}
```

Comment: Even though this isn't the original problem I had, thanks for catching an additional bug.